# Sorting of double surnames with biber

Tags: bibliographies, biber, sorting

In my list of references, there is an author with a double surname, the first part of which is also the complete surname of another author. (This is not a case of name-changing after marriage):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{SurnameSurname,
    author = {Surname-Name, Author},
    year = {2020},
    title = {A revolutionary finding},
    journal = {Journal}
}

@article{Surname,
    title = {Some research article},
    author = {Surname, Buthor},
    journal = {Journal},
    year = {2020}
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname}
\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Biber (but not BibTeX) sorts "Surname-Name" before "Surname", although the other way around is the intended output.

It is my understanding that I need to adapt the sorting scheme. But I do not know how to make my sorting scheme respect the hyphen. I've tried some `sortlocale` but none changed the sorting.

Edit: One solution is of course the `sortname` field. However, I'm curious whether there could be some automated solution.

Comment: I get `Surname` before `Surname-Name` in a current texlive. Is your system up-to-date?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Up to date in terms of what my current operating system provides, yes. I'm running TeX Live 2019 with biber 2.12. Are you running TL 2020?

Comment: I have tl2020, but it works in my tl2019 too. There I have biber 2.14.

Comment: I also cannot reproduce the problem with the MWE.